# HTML DOM node lost events

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

When I move some DOM nodes form one context to another, all some of the children nodes lost their event listeners.

HTML

```
<div><lots of deep nodes .../><div>
<div>
   <div>
     <div#newNode></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
nodes = $('div').find('nodes')
$('#newNode').html(nodes)
```

After the moving... all the nodes moved lost their events.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Be careful with the `clone` suggestions in the answers here as having multiple elements with the same ID on one DOM will break scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are copying the html, it does not have any event information with it.

You want to use [`.clone(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
$('.whatToCopy').clone(true).appendTo('#NewLocation');
```

Comment: If that's the case how about `$('#newNode').empty().append(nodes)`?

Comment: I've tried all of it.. seems like the events go to the document instead of the cloned nodes.

For example, one of the cloned nodes is a bootstrap date-picker.. 
When I move the cloned nodes to the new Parent#Node the date-picker appers on the corner Left-Top. :(

Answer (score 2):

Reconstituting or copying the HTML makes brand new DOM elements that do not have any of the event listeners of the previous nodes (the elements are created from scratch just like the original HTML in the page created elements without event listeners).  So, naturally, they won't have any of your jQuery event listeners on them unless you run new code to add event listeners to them.

If you want to move the nodes, you can just directly move the DOM elements to a different place in the DOM without using the HTML (and thus without making new DOM elements) so all the event listeners stay attached.  For example to move them:

```
nodes = $('div').find('nodes');
$('#newNode').append(nodes);
```

---

If you want to copy the nodes with event listeners attached, then you can use `.clone(true, true)` which will clone the nodes with data and events and do a deep clone (including children):

```
nodes = $('div').find('nodes');
$('#newNode').append(nodes.clone(true, true));
```

See the [jQuery reference for `.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

try using append or prepend on `$('#newNode')`.
`.html()` recreates the tags so you lose all your events and stuff